# error regarding opening the DNN website

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

When I open my website, Its shows an error in URL tab:

**The+type+initializer+for+'DotNetNuke.Professional.LicenseActivation.Licensing.LicenseManager'+threw+an+exception**

I also restore the back up of website but still this error shows.
How this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You are running Professional Edition please contact DotNetNuke Support. Your license email from DotNetNuke will have the proper contact information.